# Get records group by multiple column mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table structure

```
comment_file_id  comment_id  attachement_id  source  created_by
   33           203               42          IN        101
   35           203               46          OUT       101
   36           203               42          OUT       101
   37           203               42          OUT       101
```

i want to get only 3 records only  as records associated with attachment_id 42 are duplicates for source `OUT` , so oi have to exclude those ones.

```
    select * 
      from comments 
     where comment_id = 203 
     GROUP 
        BY source
         , created_by 
         , attachement_id ;
```

but getting errors

Comment: provide your sample output

Comment: @Fahmi i want to exclude last record i.e for comment_file_id 37 as there is records exists with attachement_id 42 with source OUT at 3rd record

Comment: @VivekSahni OK...but _which_ of the duplicates do you want to retain?

Answer (score 1):

use `min()`

```
select min(comment_file_id) as comment_file_id,comment_id,attachement_id,source
,created_by from table
group by comment_id,attachement_id,source
,created_by
```

Comment: cannot bound on limit 3 it might be exceed upto n or m

Comment: @VivekSahni what is your expected output from this sample data

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Sometimes it is better to get an answer to that question before posting your own answer :-) (not my downvote)

Comment: This happens to work for the sample data provided, but it would remove duplicates from the entire table, which the OP may not want.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin is orking fine but i want to get all records also like `select min(comment_file_id) as comment_file_id,t.*, from table t
group by comment_id,attachement_id,source
,created_by` how do i can achieve so ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` is helpful here.  We can phrase your query as a union of all records not subject to duplicate constraints, along with the single record not deemed a duplicate:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY comment_file_id) rn
    FROM comments
    WHERE comment_id = 203 AND attachement_id = 42 AND source = 'OUT'
)

SELECT comment_file_id, comment_id, attachement_id, source, created_by
FROM comments
WHERE comment_id = 203 AND (attachement_id <> 42 OR source <> 'OUT')
UNION ALL
SELECT comment_file_id, comment_id, attachement_id, source, created_by
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```